# how can I refresh image in Django HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to refresh the image after pressing the button
I include the image in static files.. im using Django with HTML
[image: py]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to fetch the image again without reloading the page you can do something like this.

```
<img id="pic" src="{% static 'images/graph.png' %}" onclick="reloadimg()" style="display:none;" />
<script>
    function reloadimg(){
        var src = "{% static 'images/graph.png' %}";
        imageObject = document.getElementById("pic");
        imageObject.style.display = 'inline-block';
        imageObject.src = src;  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, is it ok to include the script in the HTML template without including it in the static files?

Comment: thank you, can you help me to hide the image and show it only when the button pressed?

Comment: Hey, @ReemAbdulrhman there should be a link on YouTube located here that involves Javascript if you want to take a look: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-pA2uRU-OY I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In django by default if server is running on debug mode, it should refresh,

if it is not refreshing, try running command `python manage.py collectstatic` and do  hard refresh of page by Ctrl + shift + R